# Automatic deducing of the type that should be returned by operator or function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

What is the purpose of very peculiar behaviour of template conversion operator? Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

#include <cstdlib>

#define PP { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

struct A
{
    template< typename T >
    operator T () { PP; return {}; }
    template< template< typename ... > class C, typename ...types >
    operator C< types... > () { PP; return {}; }
    template< typename T >
    T operator * () { PP; return {}; }
};

static void f(int) PP

template< typename T >
struct S {};

template< typename T = void >
void g(S< T >) PP

int main()
{
    struct B {};

    // T A::operator B() [T = B]
    B{} = A{};

    // C<types...> A::operator S() [C = S, types = <void>]
    S< void >{} = A{};

    // T A::operator int() [T = int]
    // void f(int)
    f(A{});

    // void g(S<T>) [T = void]
    g({});

    // expected the same output prepended by "T A::operator S() [T = S<void>]"
    // but conversion operator does not involved after first step when matching failed
    // and default value of template parameter should be chosen to next try
    // error: no matching function for call to 'g'
    // note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'S<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'A'
    //g(A{});

    // error: indirection requires pointer operand ('A' invalid)
    //B{} = *A{};

    // error: no matching member function for call to 'operator*'
    // note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
    //B{} = A{}.operator * ();

    // error: indirection requires pointer operand ('A' invalid)
    //(*A{}).~A();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Its ability to automatically deduce a returning type required by recepient (left hand side of assignment expression or actual function argument type) is unique as far as I can see. I can't reproduce such behaviour for unary `operator *`, `operator ->`, `operator ()` and others.

#### ADDITIONAL:

I found the [trick of how to know](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d7bb34ecdab6c2e) expected type to return in implicit conversions.

Comment: Is there a tricks using template conversion operator?

Comment: So, not sure what you are asking.  Are you asking "to what use can it be put", or "why did the language designers do this"?  The first is easy and useful; the second is difficult and not that useful to anyone except language designers.

Comment: @Yakk preferably both